# Installing Cloud SQL Proxy on Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to install the Cloud MySQL Proxy on a Dataproc cluster with the initialization-action given as an example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy). I removed all the hive-metadata part because I don't need it. The proxy is installed but I can't connect to my instance. The created cloud-sql-proxy.service file looks fine:

```
> cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-sql-proxy.service 
[Unit]
Description=Google Cloud SQL Proxy
After=local-fs.target network-online.target
After=google.service
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy   -dir=/var/run/cloud_sql_proxy    -instances_metadata=attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also, if I try to get the value of `attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances` it looks fine:

```
> /usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances
> myproject-12345:europe-west1:my-db-instance=tcp:3333
```

Yet I can't connect to the instance. When I stop the service and start it again I see an error message:

```
> /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/var/run/cloud_sql_proxy -instances_metadata=attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances
2017/07/03 09:23:44 Ready for new connections
2017/07/03 09:23:44 Error on receiving new instances from metadata: metadata: GCE metadata "attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances" not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong?
In the meantime I can get this to work by using `-instances=myproject-12345:europe-west1:my-db-instance=tcp:3333` instead of using the metadata key, but I wonder why it doesn't work as provided in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle difference in how the Cloud SQL proxy interprets flags and how get_metadata_value interprets its input.

When using get_metadata_value, the attribute to read is assumed to be relative to

```
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/
```

while in the case of the Cloud SQL proxy, all paths should be relative to:

```
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/
```

So if you're intention is to have the Cloud SQL proxy read instance metadata, pass in:

```
-instances_metadata=instance/attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances
```

Comment: thanks, works with `PROXY_INSTANCES_FLAGS+=" -instances_metadata=instance/${ADDITIONAL_INSTANCES_KEY}"`

Comment: For posterity there is a PR open to fix this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/254. `ADDITIONAL_INSTANCES_KEY` is `attributes/additional-cloud-sql-instances`.